# Applying multiple codemirror scripts to one iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, codemirror

I have installed Codemirror on my website and I have almost got it where I want it I can write code in html and preview it in an iframe however I want to be able to apply a CSS text area and Javascript text area to the same iframe???

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply load both modes and give the different CodeMirror instances a different `mode` option.

Comment: But how would you combine the results of HTML+CSS+JavaScript instances and show the combined result in the iframe? I think what Otis is saying is very similar to what jsBin is doing.

Comment: Ah, I see. Umm, concatenate them in a clever way and write them to the frame? See also jsbin, which does this and is open-source at https://github.com/remy/jsbin/

Answer (score 1):

**Here's an idea worked for me**

```
<script>
var delay;

// HTML MODE
var html = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("html"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    mode: 'text/html'
});
html.on("change", function() {
clearTimeout(delay);
delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
});

// CSS MODE
var css = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("css"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    mode: 'text/css'
});
css.on("change", function() {
clearTimeout(delay);
delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
});

// Javascript MODE
var js = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("js"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    mode: 'text/javascript'
});
js.on("change", function() {
clearTimeout(delay);
delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
});

function updatePreview() {
var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;

// Preview
preview.open();
preview.write('<style type="text/css">' + css.getValue() + '</style>');
preview.write(html.getValue());
preview.write(js.getValue());
preview.close();

}
setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
</script>
```

**Hope it Helps.**